# Do assets (from the asset pallet on State[mine/mint]) have an existential deposit?

Tags: statemine, statemint, existential-deposit

I understand that in order to maintain an account in state on the Relay Chain an account needs to hold more than the Existential Deposit (1 DOT/0.000003 KSM), but I am wondering if assets deployed on Statemint/Statmine also need to maintain a minimum balance to avoid being reaped. If so how is this determined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assets (from [assets pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/assets/src/lib.rs#L18)) do not have  existential deposits but the native token ([pallet balances - ED](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L41)) does.
For example, if you want to [create a new asset in Statemine](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/kusama-statemine) and since the native token of Statemine is KSM then you need to have in your Statemine account an existential deposit of 0.000003 KSM.

However, what the asset pallet has is the notion of [Sufficiency](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/assets/src/lib.rs#L59) and the attribute [is_sufficient](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/assets/src/lib.rs#L1118)

So if an asset is deemed as sufficient (through governance) then the existential deposit is not needed.

As mentioned in the [wiki](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-assets#creation-and-management) :

> Only the network's governance mechanism can deem an asset as
> *sufficient*. A balance of a non-sufficient asset (the default) can only exist on already-existing accounts. That is, a user could not
> create a new account on-chain by transferring an insufficient asset to
> it; the account must already exist by having more than the existential
> deposit in DOT (or a sufficient asset). However, assets deemed
> *sufficient* can instantiate accounts. In the future, *sufficient* assets will be able to pay transaction fees, such that users can
> transact on Statemint without the need for DOT .

An example [proposal](https://kusama.polkassembly.io/post/1482) of this case is from RMRK where the notion of `Sufficiency` is again explained

> Sufficiency is the concept of allowing a token on Statemine to exist
> and be used without accounts needing an existential deposit of KSM to
> accept the token.

and in which they proposed to make the RMRK token sufficient so no need for existential deposit in KSM.

**Adding additional resources that give more context on the above :**

- [Sufficient and non-sufficient assets](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000181800-what-is-statemint-and-statemine-and-how-do-i-use-them-)

> To hold a non-sufficient asset in an account, the account needs to
> exist on-chain, which means it needs to have a balance in the native
> asset at least as much as the [Existential Deposit
> (ED)](https://support.polkadot.network/en/support/solutions/articles/65000168651).
> This means **0.1 DOT** on Statemint and **0.000003333 KSM** on
> Statemine. As you may have noticed, these existential deposits are ten
> times smaller than they are on the Relay Chains.
> So, to send a non-sufficient asset, you need to ensure that the
> recipient account has at least the ED. A sufficient asset doesn't
> require the account to have any balance in the native token in order
> to be received.

- [Assets](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-assets#creation-and-management)
- [Assets on Polkadot](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-integrate-assets#assets-basics)
- [Influence of Existential Deposits on account assets](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/influence-of-existential-deposits-on-account-assets)
- [Account Data Structure from Substrate Docs](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/account-data-structures/)

> The `sufficients` reference counter indicates if an account is
> self-sufficient and can exist by itself. For example, in the Assets
> pallet, an account can have sufficient number of certain assets but
> without owning any native account balance.

Answer (score 3):

The Existential Deposit (ED), transfer fees, and the deposits for proxy/multisig operations on Statemint are about 1/10th of the values on the Relay chain. So, the Existential Deposit of a Statemint account is 0.100 DOT, when compared to 1 DOT on Polkadot.